# SQL query to CSV

Tags: database, drush, importing-exporting

I'm doing some queries on my Drupal site using the `drush sql-query` command. I'd like to export the results to a CSV. Is it possible to do this via the command options, some plugin, or some other alternative method?

Comment: You can try this with `drush sql-query` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: It produces a "query failed" when tried.

Comment: How about using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module to (1) run your SQL and (2) save the report as a CSV? The same is also possible using drush ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awk part should be like this

```
drush sqlq "SELECT nid, title, alias from node 
LEFT JOIN url_alias ON url_alias.source = CONCAT('node/', node.nid)
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_myfield ON node.nid = field_data_field_myfield.entity_id 
WHERE type = 'blog' AND field_data_field_myfield.entity_id IS NULL;"| awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t"} ; {print "\""$1"\",\""$2"\",\""$3"\""}' > output.csv
```

Comment: The `awk` command doesn't work. The output is all columns of "$1,$2,$3"

Comment: For a comma separated list, the awk part has to be like:
`awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\t"} ; {print "\""$1"\","\"$2"\","\"$3"\""}' > output.csv`.
Note the backslashes which will escape the second double-quote so it will appear as an actual double-quote inside the csv.

Answer (score 3):

I found it easiest to export the results to .tsv format

- D7: `drush sql-query "SELECT nid, title FROM node LIMIT 10" > nid-title.tsv`
- D8: `drush sql-query "SELECT nid, title FROM node_field_data LIMIT 10" > nid-title.tsv`

You could also convert TSV to CSV from the linux terminal with something like:

```
cat nid-title.tsv | tr "\\t" "," > nid-title.csv
```

or with an editor like Libre Offic Calc: open .tsv, save as .csv

Comment: If `tr` is not installed use `sed`: `cat nid-title.tsv | sed "s/\t/,/g" > nid-title.csv`.